# WPF: How to bind Datagrid to navigation property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm new of WPF and .NET.
I'm developing a client for a REST service.
I have two classes:

```
namespace TcNFCCommons
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Tag
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Tag()
        {
            this.PartecipanteTag = new HashSet<PartecipanteTag>();
            this.Device = new HashSet<Device>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SerialeEvento { get; set; }
        public int IdTipo { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public int Cariche { get; set; }
        public bool Nascosto { get; set; }
        public bool Ricarica { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PartecipanteTag> PartecipanteTag { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Device> Device { get; set; }
        public virtual Evento Evento { get; set; }
        public virtual TipoTag TipoTag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and:

```
namespace TcNFCCommons
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Device
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Device()
        {
            this.Tag = new HashSet<Tag>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to create two Datagrids:

1. in the firts one I want to manage the devices entities
2. when i select a device I want to show the list of tags that are associated with the selected device
3. if I remove a row in the second datagrid, I want deassociate that tag from the selected device
4. if I add a row I want to select the tag to associate to the selected device from a combo that shows all the existing tags

I'm able to do the first step, but I don't know how to bind properly the second datagrid to make it work as described in the other 3 steps.

Here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TcNFCBackEnd.devices.DevicesControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TcNFCBackEnd.devices"
             xmlns:tags="clr-namespace:TcNFCBackEnd.tags"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1000">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="DeviceData" ObjectType="{x:Type local:DevicesProvider}" MethodName="GetObjects">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Null />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="TagData" ObjectType="{x:Type tags:TagsProvider}" MethodName="GetObjects">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Null />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <Style x:Key="CellEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid x:Name="tagGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid,Path=SelectedItem.UITag}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Tag Associati"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TagData}}" Width="200" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding UITag}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=/Label}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=/Id}"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DeviceData}}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                    <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
                </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Width="100" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Label" Binding="{Binding Label, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Width="100" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Tipo" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Tipo, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Width="100">
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <system:String>Smartphone</system:String>
                                <system:String>Totem</system:String>
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: have you searched for "parent-child" or "master-detail"? First shot on google: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application

Comment: @Mat: thanks for the link, it is a good starting point for master and detail, but what I ask for is very different; I don't know how bind my `tagGrid` and its `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to make it work in the described way. I think it's not a very original layout and UI behaviour, but I can't find nothing searching here or on Google.